# Netbeans change the .gradle directory

Tags: netbeans, gradle

I work on Windows with Netbeans 8.1.Now the .gradle directory is located in the windows user home.
I need to change the location of .gradle directory ( because of size profil limits warning ).

How can I do that ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

From the UI use the following steps:
Go to tools-->window-->options. Then select miscellaneous. Go to the Gradle tab(this is only visible if you have gradle plugin installed on netbeans)

Here you will see an option to set the gradle home and a lot of other parameters as well.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I set the system environment variable GRADLE_USER_HOME to an other directory like the following :

```
variable name : GRADLE_USER_HOME
value of variable : E:\repos\gradle
```

Then in Netbeans It works ( perhaps you have to make some clean, close and open project to refresh it )

This tips is on my blog.
Hope this help !